# Initializing linked list

Tags: java, list

When I run my driver class, my list wont initialize. This is what should be necessary to start the list.

```
public class SortedListReferenceBased implements ListInterface {
    private Node head;
    private int numItems; // number of items in list

    public SortedListReferenceBased()
    // creates an empty list
    {
        head = new Node(null);
        numItems = 0;

    } // end default constructor

    public boolean isEmpty()
    // Determines whether a list is empty
    {
        return true;
    } // end isEmpty

    public int size()
    // Returns the number of items that are in a list
    {
        return numItems;
    } // end size

    public void removeAll()
    // Removes all the items in the list
    {
        head = null;
        numItems = 0;

    } // end removeAll

    public Object get(int index) throws ListIndexOutOfBoundsException
    // Retrieves the item at position index of a sorted list, if 0 <= index <
    // size().
    // The list is left unchanged by this operation.
    // Throws an exception when index is out of range.
    {
        if (index < 0 || index >= numItems) {
            throw new ListIndexOutOfBoundsException(index + " is an invalid index");
        }
        return new Object();
    }

    public void add(Object item) throws ListException
    // Inserts item into its proper position in a sorted list
    // Throws an exception if the item connot be placed on the list
    {
        try {
            Node newNode = new Node(item);
            if (head != null) {
                int i = locateIndexToAdd(item);
                if (i >= -1 && i <= numItems) {
                    add(i, item);
                }
            } else {
                head = new Node(newNode);
                Node curr = head.getNext();
                curr.setNext(null);
                numItems++;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new ListException("Add to List failed:  " + e.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "my list wont initialize" what do you mean? How do you see that?

Comment: i have a driver class that when used should place a word at Node head, but it give me an error saying it stopped at the add method

Comment: Please post the stacktrace

Comment: can you post the stack trace and add the place of error in the posted code as an annotation, please? So we can understand the error

Comment: In the `add` method, it seems that `curr` can be `null` and you're not checking for that before calling `curr.setNext(null);`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be this part of your `add` method:

```
head = new Node(newNode);
Node curr = head.getNext();
curr.setNext(null);
numItems++;
```

I assume the `next` variable in `Node` gets initialized with `null` so `head.getNext()` returns `null` for `curr`. When you then call `curr.setNext(null)` you get a `NullPointerException`. Since this add the first entry in your list you want to set the `next` for your first element to `null`.
Also you do not have to wrap `newNode` in a `Node` since its already a node.

```
head = newNode;
head.setNext(null);
numItems++;
```

But since you initialize it with `null` anyway you don't have to do anything.

```
head = newNode;
numItems++;
```

Comment: thanks, I didn't see that I was calling the next node.